# Fundamental Subspaces: Orthonormal Bases

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

In matlab, we are asked to set A=rand(5,2)*rand(2,5)

then to set Q=orth(A), w=null(A'), S=[Q W]

the matrix S should be orthogonal. Why? (I have no clue on how to answer this)

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is an arbitrary matrix.  We note that
$$
\text{null}(A^*) = \text{image}(A)^\perp
$$
So, the columns of $Q$ form an orthonormal basis of $\text{image}(A)$, and the columns of $W$ form an orthonormal basis of $\text{image}(A)^\perp$.  Together, the columns of $[Q\;\ W]$ are an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$, which means that the matrix is orthogonal.