# Computing S*S' and comparing to eye(5)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, orthogonality

In matlab, we asked to set `A=rand(5,2)*rand(2,5)`

then to set `Q=orth(A)`, `W=null(A')`, `S=[Q W]`

Compute `S*S'`  and compare your result with `eye(5)`.

$$\text{In Theory $A^TW$ and $W^TA$ should consist entirely of zeros. Why?}$$

need help answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

The columns $w_1,\dots,w_k$ of $W$ are in the nullspace of $A^T$.  It follows that
$$
A^TW = A^T[w_1\; \cdots \; w_k] = 
[A^T w_1 \; \cdots \; A^T w_k] = 
[0\; \cdots \; 0]
$$
So, $A^TW = 0$.  It follows that $W^TA = (A^TW)^T = 0^T = 0$.

Because $S = [Q\; W]$ is orthogonal (as I explain [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1218818/81360)), `S*S'` and `eye(5)` (the $5 \times 5$ identity matrix) should be the same (up to rounding errors in the computation).